# Find solution of PDE $x \frac {\partial z} {\partial x} +y \frac {\partial z} {\partial y}=z$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **Problem**:Find solution of  Cauchy problem for the first order PDE $x \frac {\partial z} {\partial x} +y \frac {\partial z} {\partial y}=z$,on $ D= {(x,y,z): x^2 +y^2 \neq0,z>0} $ with initial condition $x^2+y^2=1,z=1$
>
> **Solution**:Using Lagrange's solution we get,
>
> $\phi \left ( x \over y \right )={y \over z}  $ where $\phi$ is some arbitrary function
>
> But I don't know "How to do this with above conditions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Euler's equation for homogeneous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity) of degree $k=1$. Hence we know that $z( \lambda x, \lambda y)=\lambda z(x,y)$ for all $\lambda>0$. Since $z \equiv 1$ on the unit circle, we find that $$z(x,y)=z \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \;z \left( \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: Absolutely right. THANKS A LOT